# SQLDelight and data classes with one to many relations in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class, kmm, sqldelight

I am trying to create a small app using Kotlin Multiplatform where i can save book titles and their authors but i'm struggling with the data classes and how to map them together so that i get the author with all of their books and the publish date.

```
CREATE TABLE book(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
publishDate INTEGER NOT NULL,
authorId INTEGER NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE author(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
name TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Here are my data classes:

```
@Serializable
data class bookEntity(
  id: Int,
  name: String,
  authorId: Int
)

@Serializable
data class authorEntity(
  id: Int,
  authorName: String
  books: List<bookEntity>
)
```

and my Query:

```
selectAuthors:
SELECT * FROM author
JOIN book ON book.authorId = author.id
WHERE book.authorId = author.id
```

i tried the following mapping but it didn't work:

```
private fun mapAuthor(
  id: Int,
  authorName: String,
  bookId: String,
  name: String,
  publishDate: Long
): Author(
  return Author (
    id = id,
    authorName = authorName,
    book = List<BookEntity>(
      id = bookId,
      name = name,
      publishDate = publishDate
    )
  )
)
```

How can i work with lists like this?
Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `ON` clause of the `JOIN` is the condition which links both tables. You don't need to repeat the condition in the `WHERE` clause. Use `WHERE` to further narrow down the query, for instance if you're searching for a specific author name.

```sql
SELECT * FROM author
JOIN book ON book.authorId = author.id
WHERE author.name LIKE 'John%';
```

If you want to query all authors, just remove the `WHERE` completely.

Also, you don't need to create data classes and do the mapping yourself. SQLDelight already creates data classes for your queries.

Comment: Please explain why this was down voted 

Answer (score 0):

You can create the query like Sven suggested and then map the joined table records into your authorEntity object using a mapper on the query.

This is how you use the mapper. You just need to adjust this to the joined columns you mentioned in your question to fill the authorEntity.

```
override fun get(id: Long): Flow<Query<Friend>>? {
   return try {
      return queries.getFriendById(
          id = id,
          mapper = { friendId, username, firstname, lastname, phone, picture, accepted ->
          Friend(
              Profile(friendId, username, firstname, lastname, phone, picture),
              accepted
          )
      }).asFlow()
  } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
      null
  }
}
```